# Ajax Post using iecors plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, xdr

To get around cross Domain issues in ie8 + 9 I started to write my own `XDomainRequest` wrapper.  Until joy, I discovered the `iecors` jQuery plugin on github
https://github.com/dkastner/jquery.iecors. It works by modifying jQuery's AJAX transaction.  I didn't have to modify my plethora of `getJSON` `AJAX` calls, which was a welcome sigh of relief.

However, when I use the `$.post` method response data is returned as a string.  This causes problems because throughout the application the functions are setup to process json objects.

I have done a lot of reading around this and I know there are a ton of common pitfalls.  But everything seems to work except for post responses.  Can I perhaps preprocess post response data to make it an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery will usually alter the returned data type based on the response headers.  Your script that returns the (hopefully valid) JSON string should emit the `Content-Type: application/json` header first.  Of course, if *everything* returned is JSON, you could always use

```
$.ajaxSetup({'dataType': 'json'})
```

Comment: How odd I was setting it in $.ajaxPrefilter like so options.dataType = "json"; but to no effect.  Works fine in setup!

Comment: @CrimsonChin that's not what prefilter is used for: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/